# Wordpress Admin Login Custom Logo

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, hacks

I know this may not be possible.But just trying to know wordpress deeply.
Is it possible to replace default admin login page with custom one?

Answer (score 2):

I personally like to use something like this. This will look for a `logo` image in your templates `/images/` folder or directory, then display it in place of the default Wordpress Logo.

```
function my_login_logo() { 
    if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/logo.png'))
        $logo = '/images/logo.png';
    else if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/logo.jpg'))
        $logo = '/images/logo.jpg';
    else if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/logo.gif'))
        $logo = '/images/logo.gif';
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.login div#login h1 a {
            background-image: url(<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory').$logo; ?>);
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-size: auto;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
<?php 
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

**Alternatively** as @G.M. suggested in the comments, you could use a more `child_theme` friendly approach like so:

```
function my_login_logo() { 
    $locate = locate_template( array('images/logo.png', 'images/logo.jpg', 'images/logo.gif'), false ); 
    if ( empty($locate) ) return;
    $base = is_child_theme() && substr_count($locate , get_stylesheet_directory()) ? get_stylesheet_directory_uri() : get_template_directory_uri();
    $logo = $base . '/images/' . basename($locate);
?>
<style type="text/css">
body.login div#login h1 a {
  background-image: url(<?php echo $logo; ?>);
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-size: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
<?php 
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

---

The following 2 functions will change where you get directed to once you click the logo banner, which in my first function I replace it with a link to the homepage.

The 2nd function will replace the hover text to the blog descriptoin that was set in `Settings` as your Tag Line.

```
/** Change Banner Link **/
function custom_loginlogo_url($url) {
    return home_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'custom_loginlogo_url' );

/** Change Link Title to Tagline **/
function custom_login_logo_link_title(){
    return get_option('blogdescription');  
}
add_filter('login_headertitle', 'custom_login_logo_link_title');
```

All these need to be placed into `function.php` for them to work.

Comment: First if/elseif/elseif statement can be replaced with a simpler (and child theme friendly) `$logo = locate_template( array('images/logo.png', 'images/logo.jpg', 'images/logo.gif'), false );`

Comment: @G.M. Maybe I'm using it incorrectly, but when I add your replacement code, I get an error since it appends `/var/www/vhosts/`

Comment: You're right. Full child theme friendly code should be `$locate = locate_template( array('images/logo.png', 'images/logo.jpg', 'images/logo.gif'), false );
$base = is_child_theme() && substr_count($locate , get_stylesheet_directory()) ? get_stylesheet_directory_uri() : get_template_directory_uri();
$logo = $base . '/images/' . basename($locate);`

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_login_logo() { ?>
<style type="text/css">
    body.login div#login h1 a {
        background-image: url(<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) ?>/images/site-login-logo.png);
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
</style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

All you need to do is replace the URL to your logo url.